# Magento - Create a Manual Invoice Number for Each Invoice (No Auto Numbering)

Tags: magento, invoices

I have a situation where we are using Magento to manage Web based orders.

However .. all invoicing is occuring through our SAP system.
I therefore need to firstly create an invoice in SAP, and then manually use that number as my invoice number in Magento.

I do understand that this is by no means an efficient way of doing things, but our business IT restrictions mean that we cannot link the systems.

Is there a way of using Manual invoice numbers within Magento ?

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Also, you should check out [The Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/).  You will probably get a much better response there